# Get rows matching across multiple column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like

```
asset_id  tag_id
1     2
2     3
3     1
2     15 
5     6
6     3
6     15
```

Now,i want all records with both tags 3 and 15, in the above case it will be 2 and 6, how do i get this without a join? 
i can get the results with this but i want to know if i can do away with join also, how do i solve if i want to get all assets with say tags 1,2 and 3?

```
select * from table a, table b where a.tag_id=3 and b.tag_id=15 and a.asset_id=b.asset_id
```

this is my example data.

```
+------+----------+------------+--------+
| id   | asset_id | asset_type | tag_id |
+------+----------+------------+--------+
| 5349 |   235362 | question   |      5 |
| 5350 |   235362 | question   |     37 |
| 5351 |   235362 | question   |     36 |
| 5352 |   235362 | question   |      7 |
| 5353 |   235362 | question   |    106 |
| 6657 |   235234 | question   |      5 |
| 6658 |   235234 | question   |     36 |
| 6659 |   235234 | question   |      5 |
| 6660 |   235234 | question   |     38 |
| 6661 |   235234 | question   |     38 |
| 6662 |   235234 | question   |     11 |
| 6663 |   235234 | question   |     11 |
| 8135 |     1234 |            |      5 |
| 8136 |     1234 |            |     36 |
| 8137 |     1234 |            |    106 |
+------+----------+------------+--------+
```

Now if i run the query

```
select group_concat(asset_id) from co_asset_tags where tag_id in (5,36,106) group by asset_id having count(*)=3
```

i get

```
+------------------------+
| group_concat(asset_id) |
+------------------------+
| 1234,1234,1234         |
| 235234,235234,235234   |
| 235362,235362,235362   |
+------------------------+
```

which is wrong, only 1234 and 235362 should have been there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Group by` and having:

```
select asset_id from table where tag_id in (...) group by asset_id having count(*) =<number of tag_id's>
```

for your example:

```
select asset_id from table where tag_id in (1,2,3) group by asset_id having count(*) =3
```

see my [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1066/4)

Comment: hey, wont this will also select assets having tags 1,2,5? because you are only comparing the count at the end to be equal to 3. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @xmen No because: `where tag_id in (1,2,3)`

Comment: But in is used for OR right? if we write in(1,2) we will get records having only 1 and only 2 as tags too.

Comment: @xmen But then the Count is 2 and not three, so they will not selected.

Comment: but in the first comment case i mentioned. say an asset was there with tags 1,2 and 5. It will be selected by where and it will also pass the count condition,as it has 3 tags. why wouldnt it come in the output?

Comment: @xmen sorry can not get you?

Comment: I mean. If there was an asset with the following rows.
assetid    tagid
  12           1
  12            2 
   12           5 
why would this not come in your query using tag_in(1,2,3) can you explain?

Comment: This will be selected.

Comment: exactly, but i dont want that row, i only want assets with tags 1,2 and 3.
here 12 has tags 1,2 and 5 and still selected.

Comment: So you make me confues. 12 1 12 2 12 5 will not be selected if you use `tag_in(1,2,3)`. Because there are only thwo selected rows and you asking for 3 rows when you are using having Count(*) =3

Comment: edited question for you with example data and wrong result

Comment: so you mean that there sould be only These three an no other?

Comment: @xmen i have added a fiddle, so you can see that this will work

Comment: yes only 2 rows should have come int the above example, but 3 are coming

Comment: Please Show theresult of  `select * from co_asset_t where asset_id=235234`

Comment: You have multiple entries with 3 and 2 thats why it is not working. makes this sence?

Comment: yes, that i observed, so i want to know 2 things, why is it not working if it has duplicate data, and how do i make it work even with duplicate data?

Comment: @xmen it doesn't work in this case, because 3 records are selected. 2 times tagid 2 and one time tag_id 3. I beleave this Kind of data makes no sence. why should one asset be connected to one tag two times?

Comment: Hmm yea, makes sense. so you would suggest me to delete the duplicate data first then?

Comment: @xmen yes if they are unnecessary i would suggest to delete them